# RKClient: how do do a simple PUT of xml body

Tags: restkit

I'm using RestKit, and have yet to come across how to do a simple PUT of a body like this:

```
 <parameters></parameters>
```

Can someone please give a code example?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a confusing PUT since your query parameter is actually titled "parameters". Are you sure that was the intention? Try something like this.

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"" forKey:@"parameters"];
[[RKClient sharedClient] put:yourURL params:params delegate:self];
```

Of course you will need to have RestKit imported, and your .h file must accept `< RKRequestDelegate >`. I hope that gets you on the right track.

You may also want to look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078570/ios-restkit-http-put-example), however I haven't implemented the suggested solution so I can't ascertain as to its efficacy.